# The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' error in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context)=>myhome(
       userEmail: userDetails!.email,
       userName: userDetails.displayName,
      )

class myhome extends StatefulWidget {
   String userName;
   String userEmail;
   myhome({required this.userName,required this.userEmail});
```

In the userEmail and userName the error is being shown. How can I fix it?

Comment: use bang`!` operator to fix this.

Comment: The error is due to that dart will assume that the value might be undefined, for a case where the value is required, So you have to override it as per @YeasinSheikh 's comment. Else perform a pre validation and then it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put a bang symbol to the variable as saying to compiler that it can't be null

```
 Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context)=>myhome(
                userEmail: userDetails.email!,
                userName: userDetails.displayName!,
                )

                class myhome extends StatefulWidget {
                String userName;
                String userEmail;
                myhome({required this.userName,required this.userEmail});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is null safety coming into play here.
The email and displayName coming from the userDetails are nullable meaning their value can be null. But the fields in your myhome class are not.
You can make those nullable by making their type to "String?".
Adding the "!" operator to "userDetails.!email" does work where you say that this field is not going to be null but it's not a good practice.
You can understand this better by going through the null safety docs
https://dart.dev/null-safety